# sub-subdomain records for public hosted zone in AWS not working

Tags: amazon-route53, dns-zone

I have added public hosted zone `foo.mydomian.io` in Route 53 and got my DNS provider to add name-servers for the sub-domain, however any records I create for mapping instances be it Type - A or CNAME don't work. If I run a `dig +trace ns` I get a response which shows the AWS NS records for my subdomain, but I still reach instances using the names `XXXX.foo.mydomain.io`

I am not sure how to further troubleshoot this, or whom to seek support in this case, is it my DNS provider or Amazon?

What I also notice in the dig output is something like this in the answer section

```
foo.mydoamin.io.    3600    IN  NS  ns-1143.awsdns-14.org.mydomain.io.
foo.mydoamin.io.    3600    IN  NS  ns-403.awsdns-50.com.mydomain.io.
foo.mydoamin.io.    3600    IN  NS  ns-1764.awsdns-28.co.uk.mydomain.io.
foo.mydoamin.io.    3600    IN  NS  ns-775.awsdns-32.net.mydomain.io.
```

I am wondering if the answer should atually be

```
foo.mydoamin.io.    3600    IN  NS  ns-1143.awsdns-14.org.
```

only?

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS provider has made an error in setting up the DNS records, by not ending the NS record with a final .

In this context, if the hostname of the record does not end with a `.`, it ends up thinking that it's a relative record.

I.e. inside the zone mydomain.io, if you make an NS record like:

```
foo.mydomain.io. 3600 IN NS ns-1143.awsdns-14.org
```

It will end up resolving as "ns-1143.awsdns-14.org.mydomain.io" whereas if you put in:

```
foo.mydomain.io. 3600 IN NS ns-1143.awsdns-14.org.
```

(Note the extra trailing .) you will get the expected results.

Contact your DNS provider and have them repair the records accordingly.